# How to execute certain code after a computed property has been evaluated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which checks the endpoint parameter in the URL and then finds the server that contains the said parameter from inside an array with servers. I am trying to execute this code every time the server computed property is evaluated:

```
this.$store.dispatch('joinServer', this.server)
this.$store.commit('setSelectedServer', this.server)
```

I do this by adding watchers. Whenever the route URL changes, the computed server property also changes and I watched for those changes and executed the code like this:

```
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
        this.serverEndpoint = this.$route.params.endpoint
    },
    server(newServer){
        this.$store.dispatch('joinServer', newServer)
        this.$store.commit('setSelectedServer', newServer)
    }
}
```

The problem is that with my code, whenever I render the component the first time, the code doesn't execute. If I change the URL endpoint, my watchers take effect and the code does get executed.

So what I'm asking is how can I execute the code after the server computed property is evaluated the first time after I visit the component?

My code:

```
<script>
import ServerRooms from '../components/ServerRooms'
import Chat from '../components/Chat'
import Members from '../components/Members'

export default {
    components: {
        ServerRooms,
        Chat,
        Members
    },
    data(){
        return {
            serverEndpoint: this.$route.params.endpoint
        }
    },
    computed: {
        server(){
            return this.$store.state.servers.find((server) => {
                return server.endpoint == '/' + this.serverEndpoint
            })
        }
    },
    watch: {
        $route(to, from) {
            this.serverEndpoint = this.$route.params.endpoint
        },
        server(newServer){
            this.$store.dispatch('joinServer', newServer)
            this.$store.commit('setSelectedServer', newServer)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't use vue.js but you could consider using .then(). Here is an example in React.js         `axios.get('https://127.0.1.1:8000/api/).then(response => {
                
                this.setState({articles: response.data});
                })`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `immediate` keyword when defining your watcher. See [vue docs on watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

> the callback will be called immediately after the start of the
> observation

E.g.

```
watch: {
    server: {
        handler(newServer){
            console.log('newServer = ' + newServer);
            this.$store.dispatch('joinServer', newServer)
            this.$store.commit('setSelectedServer', newServer)
        },
        immediate: true
    }
}
```